# Desktop Customer Lead Tracking Software .. which language is suitable C# /. VC++

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-c++, sql-server-express

I have planned to develop lead tracking software for our business which involves  Customer Tracking service.

we have systems which are shared by LAN and I want to build a software which can take care all customer details and can be assessed in all systems in a LAN.  But I am in dileama to choose the best platform to design and implement the programme...  Can any body suggest me the best platform to achieve best and stable software .. I have done some tiny applications using c#( like POS)so should I go for C#  or look for vc++ and I want to use Entity Framework as datasource object & SQL Express as a my database.

Comment: What is the reason you are considering VC++ as an option if you don't have any experience with that so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#

1. You have used it before - much better learning curve
2. Huge resources online (msdn.microsoft.com, stackoverflow.com, asp.net, etc)
3. Easier to integrate with heterogeneous systems due to mass of available frameworks

You could do:

1. RPC model using WCF Services
2. Data services client server system using WCF Data Services and/or a web interface

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever your team is best at - and C++ is a overkill here; you'll be fine with C# / SqlServer / some ORM tool ...

Answer (score 0):

Well C# can certainly achieve what you are looking to do, and if you have prior expieriance with C# it sounds like a winner to me.

Answer (score 0):

`C#` would be a better option as it is a `RAD language`. So if your team is comfortable with `C#` as well, then its a much better option than `VC++.`

Comment: C# per se is not a RAD language (the term "RAD" is typically used for dev environments like MS Access, Powerbuilder, VS Lightswitch). It is more suited to Application Development than C++, of course. 

Comment: I don't know what make you feel tht C# is not a RAD language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596957/why-is-c-a-rapid-application-development-rad-language

Comment: Well, it's just my experience what the term RAD is typically used for, and what not. As your link states correctly, using the attribute "RAD" for C# is obviously a Microsoft marketing blur, not what the term is used in most cases elsewhere.

Comment: If Microsoft considers it as RAD then why shouldn't we :)